# REST API for following a site

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, social, following

Can anyone share the code and help me on how to follow and test if you are already following a site?

Answer (score 4):

```
// Replace the siteUrl placeholder value before you run the code.
var siteUrl = "https://domain.sharepoint.com";
var followingManagerEndpoint;

// Get the SPAppWebUrl parameter from the query string and build
// the Following manager endpoint.
$(document).ready(function () {
    var appweburl;
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var param = params[i].split("=");
        if (param[0] === "SPAppWebUrl") appweburl = param[1];
    }
    followingManagerEndpoint = decodeURIComponent(appweburl) + "/_api/social.following";
    isFollowed();
});

// Check whether the current user is already following the site.
// The request body includes a SocialActorInfo object that represents
// the specified item. 
// The success function reads the response from the REST service and then
// toggles the user's following status by calling the appropriate method.
function isFollowed() {
    $.ajax( {
        url: followingManagerEndpoint + "/isfollowed",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify( { 
            "actor": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type":"SP.Social.SocialActorInfo"
                },
                "ActorType":2,
                "ContentUri":siteUrl,
                "Id":null
            } 
        }),
        headers: { 
            "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (responseData) { 
            stringData = JSON.stringify(responseData);
            jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringData);
            if (jsonObject.d.IsFollowed === true ) {
                alert('The user is currently following the site.');
                stopFollowSite();
            }
            else {
                alert('The user is currently NOT following the site.');
                followSite();
            }
        },
        error: requestFailed
    });
}

// Make the current user start following a site.
// The request body includes a SocialActorInfo object that represents
// the site to follow.
// The success function reads the response from the REST service.
function followSite() {
    $.ajax( {
        url: followingManagerEndpoint + "/follow",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify( { 
            "actor": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type":"SP.Social.SocialActorInfo"
                },
                "ActorType":2,
                "ContentUri":siteUrl,
                "Id":null
            } 
        } ),
        headers: { 
            "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (responseData) { 
            stringData = JSON.stringify(responseData);
            jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringData);
            var statusMessage = {
                0 : 'The user has started following the site. ',
                1 : 'The user is already following the site. ',
                2 : 'An internal limit was reached. ',
                3 : 'An internal error occurred. '
            }
            alert(statusMessage[jsonObject.d.Follow] + 'Status code = ' + jsonObject.d.Follow);
        },
        error: requestFailed
    } );
}

// Make the current user stop following a site.
// The request body includes a SocialActorInfo object that represents
// the site to stop following.
function stopFollowSite() {
    $.ajax( {
        url: followingManagerEndpoint + "/stopfollowing",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify( { 
            "actor": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type":"SP.Social.SocialActorInfo"
                },
                "ActorType":2,
                "ContentUri":siteUrl,
                "Id":null
            } 
        } ),
        headers: { 
            "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function () { 
            alert('The user has stopped following the site.');
        },
        error: requestFailed
    } );
}

function requestFailed(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert('Error:\n' + xhr.status + '\n' + thrownError + '\n' + xhr.responseText);
}
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945068.aspx)

Comment: Thaks it's almost complete.. but i'm having trouble with this  error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'IsFollowed' of undefined'

Comment: When are you facing this error?

Comment: i tried to view the jsonObject. but it  showing like this :<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="alphaKanban">
    <head>
        <title>app</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></sc
</html>
 what do you  think the problem?

Comment: but the post process was successfully executed XHR finished loading: POST "https://uling-e71b8136182c04.sharepoint.com/sharepointapp".

Comment: @Looytawon The above answer satisfies the need your question, though I'll really suggest you to ask a different question on how to call rest api in an app. It will help you better :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the endpoint `http://<siteCollection>/<site>/_api/social.following/isfollowed`

You should take a look at this very detailed MSDN article: [Following people and content REST API reference for SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/office/Dn194080.aspx#bk_IsFollowed).

Answer (score 0):

we have ready made examples on MSDN to follow , sites, documents, tags and people
[REST Social API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945068.aspx).

Comment: i already tried the isfollowed REst api code .. the post was a success but when i tried to view the json form of the response i was confused when it returns hmtl tags?? wwooaahh?? what the problem?

Comment: are you using a SharePoint app or you executing the code in sharepoint site itself?

Comment: Im building a sharepiont app  specifically a sharepoint hosted app !

Comment: Ok, you said you are getting the HTML response. That means something wrong with your endpoint url formation. you might be getting  "pagenotfound.aspx page markup in response. Do one thing, open the page in Chrome, copy the response you are getting in REST call. Open browser dev tools(F12). goto elements section, right click on html tag->edit as html. replace the whole markup with your response text in the editable box, click somewhere else on the browser document area. You will see the page that you are getting in the response. reply here what the page has.

Comment: i exactly recieving response like this i tried to view the jsonObject. but it showing like this :<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml";data-ng-app="alphaKanban"><head><title>app</title><script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></sc </html>    in the  jsonObject but  i think the post request was successful coz it shows 'XHR finished loading: POST "https://uling-e71b8136182c05.sharepoint.com/sharepointkanbo.

Comment: Ok, I'm not able to figure out the actual cause with this markup. can you try the Utility functions posted here https://sharepointatwork.wordpress.com/2015/05/09/add-followunfollow-button-in-listview-webparts-for-document-libraries-using-jslink/  (second code snipppet has the Utility functions to load isfollowed, and follow/unfollow), pass the actortype as 2 and  pass appWeburl for "siteurl" parameter, and pass the site url (which you want follow) to "documentOrSiteUrl" parameter.

Comment: ooh? Look I've read this post of yours http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156454/rest-api-for-following-a-site-in-sharepoint    so i implemented it .. im convince but still having some trouble :( ... but i think we're almost there.. @sekhar

Comment: What is the exact error  you are getting now? were you able to make the POST requests? are you still getting the Same error?

Comment: Im going to commnent in this site Sir --> https://sharepointatwork.wordpress.com/2015/05/09/two-reasons-not-to-use-the-ajax-with-sharepoint-rest-calls/   ..! kindly check .. :)

Comment: replied in the site.